# Nginx - Getting 400 while downloading a file from AWS S3 with amz_request_id as empty

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

We have a app server which passes a S3 url back to nginx server . Nginx server in turns downloads the file from S3 and sends it as a response back.

Issue is we are getting 400 for nginx- S3 interaction. Strange thing is that amz_request_id is empty for this interaction.

Can any one help here.

Comment: It should be x-amz-request-id... but can you capture the interaction?

Comment: Yes right it is x-amz-request-id . No I  cannot capture the interaction . Only my nginx.conf contains the log format and it logs the result in that format.

Comment: Just to add in the nginx log format all  variables with "http_sent_*" are coming empty in the log. Is it possible that nginx might not be calling S3 at all??

Comment: You can capture the interaction with something like [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).  If you are using https to communicate with S3, you'll need to temporarily switch that to http.